# Trying to update a Dell laptop from Ubuntu 14.04 to 20.04

Tags: 14.04, dell

So I've been trying to update the computer for some time, and I can't didn't the answer of how to do it. I've got a Dell Inspiron 3558 and it's running Ubuntu 14.04. I want to update it to the 20.04 ver.

It's my completely first time using any kind of Linux software so I don't really have much idea of what I'm doing. I've tried the Software updater, but it prompts me to a window something like:

„Failed to download repository information
Check your Internet connection.“

I've tried to update it via the Terminal, haven't got much luck with it aswell.

Comment: Take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades ... it describes upgrade from an EOL version (as 14.04 is),

Comment: There is no upgrade path from an EOL version of Ubuntu (14.04) to a current LTS version (20.04). You will need to backup anything important and carry out a full install of 20.04

Comment: I have 0 important files on it, it's a completely new computer, just with an older version. How do I install the 20.04 ver? I have downloaded the 20.04 iso file, but I have no idea how to install it.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Oh, okay. That I didn't know. In this time period I've been thinking, and I want to go to Windows 10. Is there an easy way of doing it?